# Include deque in C

Tags: c, deque

I have troubles to include deque in my C code. I thought that deque should be a standard library, but when I am trying to include it with `#include <deque>` the compiler's answer is: `No such file or directory`.
I was searching for header in files given by

```
gcc -print-prog-name=cc1 -v
```

and there is really no deque to be found.
Does it exist such library for C and how can I install it? I don't want to write my own implementation.

Comment: You might want to consider using C++ rather than C, since deque is part of the standard C++ library.

Comment: Where is you code? [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/deque/) you can find working example of `#include <deque>`, but it is only for c++.

Comment: If you mean the C++ [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) class, using the `<deque>` header file, then you're out of luck, because it's a ***C++*** class. If you're looking for a pure C library, you should turn to your favorite search engine.

Comment: Lots of examples for C around [**Queues**](http://www.cs.uah.edu/~rcoleman/Common/CodeVault/Code/Code130_Queue.html). As one example.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin A [deque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deque) is similar to a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29) but it's not quite the same.

Answer (score 3):

There is no header file for deque in C. Either you have to write your own implementation or you have to switch to C++ to get it from standard library.

Comment: Some non-standard C libraries might offer some *deque* implementations (perhaps thru macros in header files).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Even if there was a C implementation of deque, the header would most likely be `<deque.h>` and not `<deque>` — the suffix-less header names are distinctively for "standard C++".

Answer (score 1):

Standard C does not know about *deque*-s. Some libraries (SGLIB or Glib from GTK, etc...) might provide them.

On Linux with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++`, standard header files for C++ are in `/usr/include/c++/4.9` (for `g++` version 4.9). Compile with `g++ -Wall -g -H` your C++ code if you want to know which header files are included.

C++ is not the same as C!